# How must be android display resolution?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova

I will develop a сross-platform mobile application. using `Phonegap`. My desinger ask me in how resolution must be application design maket, but i don't know. For `iphone 2` variants: `640×960` and `640×1136` . What to choose for android? `720×1280` and `320×480`? Help me!

Comment: Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Targeting Screens from Web Apps** http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

You basically have to target different device densities. E.g.

```
#header {
    background:url(medium-density-image.png);
}

@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    /* CSS for high-density screens */
    #header {
        background:url(high-density-image.png);
    }
}

@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 0.75) {
    /* CSS for low-density screens */
    #header {
        background:url(low-density-image.png);
    }
}
```

For me dealing with multiple screens for phonegap android was a pain, so I build most of the UI using pure css.